# Mybatis override mapper XML in submodule

Tags: spring-data, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am using Spring Boot with mybatis.
I have one common module that defines `@Repository Mapper` and appropriate `.XML` document for the mapper.

In other module, that uses common module I want sligtly change `.XML` document. How can I do that?

Comment: There is no overriding XML. You will have to modularize the XML in the core module. "How" depends on the details of the "slight change".